# Generate generic function that filter my entity data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I have entity(student) with the following fields

```
int code;
string name ;
bool active;
```

I want to create generic function that I will pass to it string condition as parameter
like

```
"where active == 1"
```

and this function will query on mentioned entity .

like following example

```
public List<Student> getdatafiltered(string condition)
{
    return context.students.where(condition).Tolist();
}
```

To call function it will call like following two examples

```
getdatafiltered("where active = 1");

getdatafiltered("where name like'%myname%'");
```

Comment: That's a rather general question and you've not really showed any effort at figuring out where, that's why you're getting downvoted. https://github.com/tbd-develop/roastpotato I worked on something similar a few years ago, you could look at that and see what you can figure out.

Comment: See [DynamicLINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).

Comment: thanks a lot ,  DynamicLINQ saves my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an `Expression<Func<Student, bool>>` to the method:

```
public List<Student> GetDataFiltered(Expression<Func<Student, bool>> condition)
{
    return context.students.Where(condition).ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
var students = GetDataFiltered(s => s.Active == 1);
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i used your solution with some changes that meet my business